# Reshaping a Large File

Tags: excel, csv, stata

I have a large .csv file with 8 variables and about 350,000 observations. In this file, each actual observation is actually split up into 105 rows. That is, each row has data for one specific demographic, and there are 105 demographic cuts (all relating to the same event). This makes it very difficult to merge this file with others.

I would like to change it so that there are 3,500 observations with variables for demographic statistics. I've tried creating a macro, but I haven't had much luck.

[This is what it looks like now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq2l2.png)

[This is what I'd like it to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDhdP.png)

This way, each ID is a unique observation. I think that this will make it much easier to work with. I can use either Stata or Excel. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show your attempts. In Stata, run `help reshape`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried reshape, but it tells me that "There are observations within i(program_no) with the same value of j(tag_no)," which isn't true. I did a `by tag_no: sum program_no`, and every tag had 3300 observations, meaning that each program_no had the same 105 tags.

Comment: The variables `program_no` and `tag_no` don't even appear in the example data you posted, so it's difficult for me to follow. For future questions: the idea is that you describe your problem, post related code (and maybe some example data), exact errors you're getting (if any) and explain why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

So here is an example with what I understand you want:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

input id store date cut
1 5 1 1
1 5 1 2
2 8 1 1
2 9 1 2
2 8 2 3
end

format date %td

set seed 012385
gen val1 = floor(runiform()*1000)
gen val2 = floor(runiform()*2000)

list, sepby(id)

*----- what you want ? -----

reshape wide val1 val2, i(id store date) j(cut)

list, sepby(id)
```

My `id` variable is numerical, as are the `cut`s (see `help destring` and `help encode` to convert). The example data is also a bit more complex than the one you posted (in case your example is not representative enough).

The missings (`.`) that result are expected. `val11` is to be interpreted as `val1` of `cut == 1`. `val21` as `val2` of `cut == 1`. `val12` as `val1` of `cut == 2`, and so on. So when `id == 1`, `val13` and `val23` are missing because this person does not appear with `cut ==3`.

I hope that was clear enough for you to apply to your data.